# How to fix 'The Decimals'

Tags: powershell

I am pulling the info from a SharePoint list. Everything is ok, but the results from the list prints as 2018.0000000 for the year column and the results from current_high and current_medium prints as 4.0000000, 26.0000000 respectively. I have tried all the functions float, decimal, round everything. But I couldn't round of the 0's. Can anyone help me on this one?

```
Select-Object ows_Year, ows_Status, ows_App, ows_cycle, ows_Current_Critical,
    ows_Current_High, ows_Current_Medium, @{Name='Result'; Expression={
        ForEach-Object {
            $d1 = (Get-Date).ToString("MM-dd")
            $d2 = (Get-Date 2018-12-28).ToString("MM-dd")

            if ($d1 -eq $d2) {
                if ($_.ows_Cycle -eq 'Cycle 1') {
                    if ([int]($_.ows_Current_Critical) -eq 0 -and [int]($_.ows_Current_High) -eq 0 -and [int]($_.ows_Current_Medium) -eq 0) {
                        'Pass'
                    } else {
                        'Fail'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }} |
```

Comment: There might be another way, but couldn't you just cast them to [int] - like you do in the `If` statement --> `Select-Object @{Name="Year", Expression={[int]ows_Year}} ...`

Comment: Tried, but its not working bud @mhhollomon

Comment: The expression should be `[int]$_.ows_Year`, but other than that the suggested calculated property should do what you want. If it doesn't please [edit] your question and show your updated code.

Comment: Thank you @mhhollomon it works perfectly

Comment: Thank you @AnsgarWiechers it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though guys in comments already pointed out how to perform such task it still might be a little confusing. So all together:

```
Select-Object @{Name='ows_Year'; Expression={[Int]$_.ows_Year}}, ows_Status, ows_App, ows_cycle, ows_Current_Critical,
    ows_Current_High, ows_Current_Medium, @{Name='Result'; Expression={
        ForEach-Object {
            $d1 = (Get-Date).ToString("MM-dd")
            $d2 = (Get-Date 2018-12-28).ToString("MM-dd")

            if ($d1 -eq $d2) {
                if ($_.ows_Cycle -eq 'Cycle 1') {
                    if ([int]($_.ows_Current_Critical) -eq 0 -and [int]($_.ows_Current_High) -eq 0 -and [int]($_.ows_Current_Medium) -eq 0) {
                        'Pass'
                    } else {
                        'Fail'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }} |
```